# Splitting a string in R

Tags: r

Consider:

```
x<-strsplit("This is an example",split="\\s",fixed=FALSE)
```

I am surprised to see that x has length 1 rather than length 4:

```
> length(x)
[1] 1
```

like this, x[3] is null. But If I unlist, then:

```
> x<-unlist(x)
> x
[1] "This"    "is"      "an"      "example"
> length(x)
[1] 4
```

only now x[3] is "an".

Why wasn't that list originally by length 4 so that elements can be accessed by indexing? This gives troubles to access the splitted elements, since I have to unlist first.

Comment: Because, as stated in `?strsplit` the value returned is: "A list of the same length as x, the i-th element of which contains the vector of splits of x[i]". You gave it a vector of length one, so you got a list of length one, whose first element contained the vector of splits.

Comment: You can still access the elements without unlisting via `x[[1]][3]`

Answer (score 2):

This allows `strsplit` to be vectorized for its input argument. For instance, it will allow you to split a vector such as:

```
x <- c("string one", "string two", "and string three")
```

into a `list` of split results.

You do not need to `unlist`, but rather, you can refer to the element by a combination of its list index and the vector index. For instance, if you wanted to get the second word in the second item, you can do:

```
> x <- c("string one", "string two", "and string three")
> y  <- strsplit(x, "\\s")
> y[[2]][2]
[1] "two"
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because `strsplit` generates a list containing each element (word).
Try

```
> x[[1]]
#[1] "This"    "is"      "an"      "example"
```

and

```
> length(x[[1]])
#[1] 4
```